# Angular - StartDate and EndDate comparison validator not displaying error message

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

In Angular-14 project, I am implementing Datepicker using BsDatepickerModule datepicker in ngx-bootstrap. I have to validate that StartDate should not be greater than EndDate, and I don't want to use DateRange picker, so I have StartDate and EndDate separately.

date-comparison-validator.ts:

```
import { AbstractControl, ValidationErrors, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

export function DateComparisonValidator(dateCompareControlName: string) {

    let thisDateControl: AbstractControl;
    let otherDateControl: AbstractControl;

    return function DateComparisonValidator(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
        if (!control.parent) {
            return null;
        }
        if (!thisDateControl) {
            thisDateControl = control;
            otherDateControl = control.parent.get(dateCompareControlName) as AbstractControl;
            if (!otherDateControl) {
                throw new Error('dateLessThanOrEqualsValidator(): other control is not found in parent group');
            }
            otherDateControl.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
                thisDateControl.updateValueAndValidity();
            });
        }
        if (!otherDateControl || !otherDateControl.value) {
            return null;
        }
        const date1 = thisDateControl.value;
        const date2 = otherDateControl.value;
        if (date1 !== null && date2 !== null && date1 > date2) {
            return {
                'date_less_than_or_equal': true
            };
        }
        return null;
    };
}
```

Then the component.ts:

```
import { DateComparisonValidator } from 'src/app/shared/validators/date-comparison-validator';


  createTransactionForm = this.fb.group({
      startDate: ['', [Validators.required, DateComparisonValidator('endDate')]],
      endDate: ['', [Validators.required]]
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.createTransaction();
  }

  createValidate() {
    if (!this.createTransactionForm.valid) {
      this.createTransactionForm.markAllAsTouched();
      return;
    }
  }
  get fc() {
    return this.createTransactionForm.controls;
  };
```

component.html:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="startDate">Start Date</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i></span>
        </div>
        <input type="text"
        placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY"
        class="form-control"
        formControlName='startDate'
        bsDatepicker
        [minDate]="minStartDate"
        [bsConfig]="{ isAnimated: true, dateInputFormat: 'DD-MM-YYYY', returnFocusToInput: true, showClearButton: true, clearPosition: 'right' }">
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="fc['startDate'].touched && fc['startDate'].invalid" class="alert alert-danger">
        <div *ngIf="fc['startDate'].errors && fc['startDate'].errors['required']">Start Date field is required!</div>
        <div *ngIf="fc['startDate'].errors && fc['startDate'].errors['DateComparisonValidator']">Start Date must be less than End Date!</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="endDate">End Date<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i></span>
        </div>
        <input type="text"
        placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY"
        class="form-control"
        formControlName='endDate'
        bsDatepicker
        [minDate]="minEndDate"
        [bsConfig]="{ isAnimated: true, dateInputFormat: 'DD-MM-YYYY', returnFocusToInput: true, showClearButton: true, clearPosition: 'right' }">
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="fc['endDate'].touched && fc['endDate'].invalid" class="alert alert-danger">
        <div *ngIf="fc['endDate'].errors && fc['endDate'].errors['required']">End Date field is required!</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Close
    
       Submit

When StartDate is greater than EndDate, I expected to see this message. But no message was displayed.

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: please share a stackblitz with the issue replicated! and screenshots of output needed!

Answer (score 1):

Cross-control validators should be set on the form, not on the controls. This is because a control will update the parent group, but no its brother controls., whereas a group will update all of its children.

```js
  createTransactionForm = this.fb.group({
      startDate: ['', [Validators.required]],
      endDate: ['', [Validators.required]]
    }, { validators: [DateComparisonValidator('endDate')] });
  }
```

Of course, update your validator accordingly.

Comment: There is no need for passing control name to validator factory `DateComparisonValidator()`. Validator will receive FormGroup on control's value changes.

Comment: @EdmundsFolkmanis that's not the problem here, but you're partially wrong : if you do not pass the name of the control, then the validator is only usable on this particular form group. If he wants to re-use it, then he would have to duplicate the code. SO you're right & wrong at the same time, depending on what he tries to achieve !